# Reasoning behind C sockets sockaddr and sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm looking at functions such as `connect()` and `bind()` in C sockets and notice that they take a pointer to a `sockaddr` struct. I've been reading and to make your application AF-Independent, it is useful to use the `sockaddr_storage` struct pointer and cast it to a `sockaddr` pointer because of all the extra space it has for larger addresses.

What I am wondering is how functions like `connect()` and `bind()` that ask for a `sockaddr` pointer go about accessing the data from a pointer that points at a larger structure than the one it is expecting. Sure, you pass it the size of the structure you are providing it, but what is the actual syntax that the functions use to get the IP Address off the pointers to larger structures that you have cast to `struct *sockaddr`?

It's probably because I come from OOP languages, but it seems like kind of a hack and a bit messy.

Answer (score 67):

Functions that expect a pointer to `struct sockaddr` probably typecast the pointer you send them to `sockaddr` when you send them a pointer to `struct sockaddr_storage`. In that way, they access it as if it was a `struct sockaddr`.

`struct sockaddr_storage` is designed to fit in both a `struct sockaddr_in` and `struct sockaddr_in6`

You don't create your own `struct sockaddr`, you usually create a `struct sockaddr_in` or a `struct sockaddr_in6` depending on what IP version you're using. In order to avoid trying to know what IP version you will be using, you can use a `struct sockaddr_storage` which can hold either. This will in turn be typecasted to `struct sockaddr` by the connect(), bind(), etc functions and accessed that way.

You can see all of these structs below (the padding is implementation specific, for alignment purposes):

```
struct sockaddr {
   unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
   char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};


struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};


struct sockaddr_in6 {
    u_int16_t       sin6_family;   // address family, AF_INET6
    u_int16_t       sin6_port;     // port number, Network Byte Order
    u_int32_t       sin6_flowinfo; // IPv6 flow information
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     // IPv6 address
    u_int32_t       sin6_scope_id; // Scope ID
};

struct sockaddr_storage {
    sa_family_t  ss_family;     // address family

    // all this is padding, implementation specific, ignore it:
    char      __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];
    int64_t   __ss_align;
    char      __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];
};
```

So as you can see, if the function expects an IPv4 address, it will just read the first 4 bytes (because it assumes the struct is of type `struct sockaddr`. Otherwise it will read the full 16 bytes for IPv6).

Comment: So suppose I had a pointer to a  `struct sockaddr_storage` called `sas` and all the fields in the structure have been duly populated with the address and address family. I now perform this: `struct sockaddr *s = (struct sockaddr*)sas`. How would I get the address off of `s` now?

Comment: you wouldn't use a `struct sockaddr` directly. What you would do is typecast it back to `sockaddr_storage` or `sockaddr_in` and then read it. As you can see from my post `sockaddr` has enough space to fit an IPv4 or v6 address. Having said that, I don't know why you would want to typecast to `struct sockaddr` for anything other than for parameters who's functions require it. `struct sockaddr` is not meant for 'programmer use'.

Comment: I am reading a book that says sockaddr isn't large enough to hold sockaddr_in6.

Comment: Well, the size of sockaddr is 16, while the size of sockaddr_storage is 128 bytes. Since the IPv6 address is 16 bytes, its hard to see how sockaddr would accomodate the IPv6 address.

Comment: If someone is confused by sa_len / sin_len: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23627149/2013911 (in short: these attributes are implementation specific => not portable)

Comment: @ashu Because 2 bytes of sockaddr are used up for storing sa_family, and so the remaining 14 bytes wont be able to accommodate the ipv6 address

Comment: From somebody who also has a OOP background: Is it using a union under the hood?

Answer (score 11):

In C++ classes with at least one virtual function are given a TAG. That tag allows you to `dynamic_cast<>()` to any of the classes your class derives from and vice versa. The TAG is what allows `dynamic_cast<>()` to work. More or less, this can be a number or a string...

In C we are limited to structures. However, structures can also be assigned a TAG. In fact, if you look at all the structures that *theprole* posted in his answer, you will notice that they all start with 2 bytes (an unsigned short) which represents what we call the family of the address. This defines exactly what the structure is and thus its size, fields, etc.

Therefore you can do something like this:

```
int bind(int fd, struct sockaddr *in, socklen_t len)
{
  switch(in->sa_family)
  {
  case AF_INET:
    if(len < sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
    {
      errno = EINVAL; // wrong size
      return -1;
    }
    {
      struct sockaddr_in *p = (struct sockaddr_in *) in;
      ...
    }
    break;

  case AF_INET6:
    if(len < sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6))
    {
      errno = EINVAL; // wrong size
      return -1;
    }
    {
      struct sockaddr_in6 *p = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) in;
      ...
    }
    break;

  [...other cases...]

  default:
    errno = EINVAL; // family not supported
    return -1;

  }
}
```

As you can see, the function can check the `len` parameter to make sure that the length is enough to fit the expected structure and therefore they can `reinterpret_cast<>()` (as it would be called in C++) your pointer. Whether the data is correct in the structure is up to the caller. There is not much choice on that end. These functions are expected to verify all sorts of things before it uses the data and return -1 and `errno` whenever a problem is found.

So in effect, you have a `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6` that you (reinterpret) cast to a `struct sockaddr` and the `bind()` function (and others) cast that pointer back to a `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6` after they checked the `sa_family` member and verified the size.

Comment: Although this is not a c++ question, maybe you could clarify, that not all c++ classes have a TAG, but only the ones with at least one virtual function.

Comment: @MikeMB The OP wrote: _"It's probably because I come from OOP languages"_, which I am thinking means he wants to understand how C works compared to what he learned before.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have expressed myself more clearly: I've had no problem with you referencing c++ whatsoever. I just wanted to make sure that -***although** it is not a question that is addressing c++ programmers* -  the parts that **do** refer to c++ are as precise as possible (in case a c++ beginner does stumble over it, as I did),